# add two numbers in a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to add numbers from two linked lists and put it in a third one. It adds well but my code blocks compiler stops responding while running this code possibly because of an infinite loop or some exception.

Following code adds two numbers stored in reverse order in a linked list.

```
struct Node{
    int x;
    Node* next;
};

class LinkedList{

    public:
        Node* head;
        LinkedList(){
            head = NULL;
        }

        void addNode(int num){
            Node* n = new Node();
            n->x = num;
            n->next = NULL;
            if(head == NULL){
                head = n;
            }else{
                Node* n1 = head;
                while(n1 != NULL){
                    if(n1->next == NULL){
                        n1->next = n;
                        break;
                    }
                    n1 = n1->next;
                }
            }
        }

        int popNode(){
            int num = NULL;
            if (head != NULL){
                num = head->x;
                head = head->next;
            }else{
                cout << "Yay" << "\n";
                num = NULL;
            }

            return num;
        }

        void printList(){
            Node* n1 = head;
            while(n1 != NULL){
                if(n1->next == NULL){
                    cout << n1->x << "\n";
                }else{
                    cout << n1->x << "->";
                }

                n1 = n1->next;
            }
        }

};

LinkedList* add_nums(LinkedList* l1, LinkedList* l2) {
    LinkedList l3;

    int num1= (*l1).popNode();
    int num2= (*l2).popNode();
    int carry = 0;

    while(num1 != NULL || num2 != NULL){
        int num3 = num1+num2+carry;

        if (num3 > 9){
            int temp = num3 % 10;
            carry = (num3 - temp)/10;
            num3 = temp;
        }

        l3.addNode(num3);
        l3.printList();
        num1 = (*l1).popNode();
        num2 = (*l2).popNode();
    }

    return &l3;

}



int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  LinkedList list1;
  LinkedList list2;
  list1.addNode(2);
  list1.addNode(4);
  list1.addNode(3);
  list2.addNode(5);
  list2.addNode(6);
  list2.addNode(4);
  (*(add_nums(&list1, &list2))).printList();
  return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Changes to code i should do after inputs from answers below:

1. I should change integer initializations from NULL to 0.
2. Should use LinkedList objects to terminate my loop.
3. Should change how i access the functions from a pointer

Thanks everyone.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Agreed. That way you will be able to answer why it ***stops responding while running this code possibly because of an infinite loop or some exception*** instead of guessing.

Comment: `return &l3;`: You return reference to local variable: UB.

Comment: All bets are off when your program contains Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: You'd better use the arrow operator instead of the star and dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

1. IMHO you might be making a wrong choice. The STL provides data structures for (doubly linked) [list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) and [forward list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/forward_list/forward_list/) (which is singly linked). Maybe you want to use those. You can expect them to be efficient enough, bug free and important to know about if you want to be a proficient C++ programmer.
2. It would make sense to let someone do a code review (there is a code review StackExchange site); e.g. naming the integer variable `x` in the linked list is probably not considered a good practise.
3. You did not tell us what is wrong about your program. This is expected in SO. Your question qualifies for "off-topic (why is this code not working?)". You provided the program, which is good. But you did not provide your expected input and output. What is your program expected to do? If I consider your `main` function as a test, then **what result did you expect ?**
4. see below some errors/warnings

In the function `popNode`

```
int num = NULL; // should be 0, it's an integer
...
num = NULL; // same reason
```

In the functions `add_nums`

```
LinkedList l3; // it's a local variable (see return below)
...
while(num1 != NULL || num2 != NULL) // again num1 and num2 are integers
....
return &l3; // address of a local variable :-(
```

I think it is better you declare the variable `l3` as a pointer to `LinkedList`:

```
LinkedList *l3 = new LinkedList;
... // adapt the code to use l3 appropriately
return l3;
```

Comment: The last part solved my issue.. discovered it on my own though. I have ask however if i assign 0 for integers and check for 0 in my code i'll get false positives and code might not work. Why is assigning NULL wrong to integers?

Comment: My advice is to ask a new question about that since it has nothing to do with the UB / crash. Please don't try to change the topic of this question since it is answered / accepted. Also you will have to be more specific.

Comment: I have mentioned what my program is supposed to do in the description. I am adding numbers in two linked lists.

Comment: I understand what you are doing but don't even remotely understand the problem of false positives.

Comment: Maybe i said it wrong. I am checking in my method `add_two_numbers` if the numbers are null as a way to end the loop. If one of the numbers is 0 my loop ends before the lists end. This is what i meant by false positive.

Answer (score 2):

As others in comments say, your error is this one: `return &l3;`

`l3` is a local object and is deleted just before the end of the function, like any object that is not dinamically allocated. This is because of the **scope** of your LinkedList object.

You should have written:

```
LinkedList* l3 = new LinkedList();
//...
//...
return l3;
```

this function now returns a pointer to your object.

NB: the variable `l3`, which contains the pointer, is deleted just before the function, but it doesn't matter because the object lifetime is not bound to the function anymore.